# Multiple placeholder text color in iOS

Tags: ios, uitextfield

Is it possible to have multiple color text in a placeholder?

For example

> Write Text - I will prepend this.

"Write Text" will be black, while "I will prepend this." will be grey.

Comment: You can use `NSAttributedString` for that.

Comment: Are you talking about the `placeholder` attribute of `UITextField`? If so, see the `attributedPlaceholder` attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Multiple Textfiled placeholder in ios.**

```
self.txt_First.attributedPlaceholder = [self String:@"Brewery (Sierra Nevada)" Range:7];
```

In above textfield first seven character is red and other are gray.

**Use the below mehod for setting multiple color.**

```
-(NSAttributedString *)String:(NSString *)str Range:(int )Rannge
{
    NSMutableAttributedString *attString =
    [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc]
     initWithString:str];

    [attString addAttribute: NSForegroundColorAttributeName
                      value: [UIColor redColor]
                      range: NSMakeRange(0,Rannge)];

    [attString addAttribute: NSForegroundColorAttributeName
                      value: [UIColor graycolor]
                      range: NSMakeRange(Rannge + 1,str.length - Rannge -1)];

    return attString;

}
```

**Multiple placeholder color Output :**

[image]

Comment: Does not work on UITextField.attributedPlaceholder in iOS 9.3.2

Comment: @NicolasBuquet http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33414757/how-to-change-uitexefield-placeholder-color-and-fontsize-using-swift-2-0/33415013#33415013

Comment: The problem is not to change the font or color of placeholder, but to use `multiple`fonts or colors in one attributedPlaceholder. That is not possible using `attributedplaceholderù property actually. You link does not show how to use multiple different attrributes simultaneously.

Answer (score 0):

I have Simple way for this .

Add `UILabel` in `UITextField` below and set `UITextField` `clearColor` .and set your `UILabel` text as you required and set that text color same as placeholder color .

Comment: why not just use attributedPlaceholder?

Comment: @Daij-Djan i know., but it is simple way.,

Comment: This is not a simple way. This is much more difficult than using `attributedPlaceholder`.