# How to change UITextfield placeholder color and fontsize using swift 2.0?

Tags: ios, swift2, xcode7

How to change `UITextfield` `placeholder` & `fontsize` in SWIFT 2.0?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26076202/988169

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Changing Placeholder Text Color with Swift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26076054/changing-placeholder-text-color-with-swift)

Answer (score 85):

**#1. set Placeholder textfield color Programmatically**

```
    var myMutableStringTitle = NSMutableAttributedString()
    let Name  = "Enter Title" // PlaceHolderText

    myMutableStringTitle = NSMutableAttributedString(string:Name, attributes: [NSFontAttributeName:UIFont(name: "Georgia", size: 20.0)!]) // Font
    myMutableStringTitle.addAttribute(NSForegroundColorAttributeName, value: UIColor.redColor(), range:NSRange(location:0,length:Name.characters.count))    // Color
    txtTitle.attributedPlaceholder = myMutableStringTitle
```

**OR**

```
txtTitle.attributedPlaceholder = NSAttributedString(string:"Enter Title", attributes: [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: yellowColor])
```

Note : `Name` is your placeholder of `textField`.

**PlaceHolder TextFiled :**

[image]

**-------------------------------- OR -------------------------------------**

**#2. set Placeholder textfield color at runtime attribute**

1. Set textfield placeHolder text `Enter Title`

   [image]
2. Click on identity inspector of textfield property.

   [image]
3. User Define Runtime Attributes, add color attributes

   Key Path :  `_placeholderLabel.textColor`

   Type     :  `Color`

   value    :   `Your Color or RGB value`

   [image]

   **PlaceHolder TextFiled :**

   [image]

Comment: The 2nd solution was best for me, I wanted to group all the fields in a `IBOutletCollection` however I was unsure how to define each UITextfields placeholder strings. This way works perfect for Swift 3.

Comment: 5 years working on iOS and didn't know the second solution ! Perfect ! Thank you :)

Comment: I was reading about the second solution and it could have some problem in production apparently because Apple can reject it

Comment: now (for swift 5, 13.4.1) it should be placeholderLabel.textColor instead of _placeholderLabel.textColor

Answer (score 17):

**Updated for Swift 3**

If you want to change the UITextField Placeholder color for Swift 3, use the following lines of code:

```
let yourTextFieldName = UITextField(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 180, height: 21))
yourTextFieldName.attributedPlaceholder = NSAttributedString(string: "placeholder text", attributes: [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.white])
```

Answer (score 14):

**Updated for Swift 5**

For swift 5.0 use **NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor** instead of **NSForegroundColorAttributeName**

So, do it like so

```
textField.attributedPlaceholder = NSAttributedString(string: "placeholder text", attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.white])
```

Answer (score 10):

For swift 4 instead of

> NSForegroundColorAttributeName

use

> NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor

Comment: this is not an answer for a question

Answer (score 6):

You can try with this sample code

```
let  textFld = UITextField();
textFld.frame = CGRectMake(0,0, 200, 30)
textFld.center = self.view.center;
textFld.attributedPlaceholder = NSAttributedString(string:"Test Data for place holder", attributes:[NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.blueColor(),NSFontAttributeName :UIFont(name: "Arial", size: 10)!])
self.view.addSubview(textFld)
```

Answer (score 3):

Placeholder for textfield **Objective C**

```
NSString* str = @"Placeholder text...";                                    
NSRange range1 = [str rangeOfString:@"Placeholder text..."];


NSMutableAttributedString *attributedText = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:str];
[attributedText setAttributes:@{
                                NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont fontWithName:customFont_NotoSans_Regular size:13.0]
                                }
                        range:range1];

[attributedText addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor whiteColor] range:range1];

txtFld.font = [UIFont fontWithName:customFont_NotoSans_Regular size:13.0];
txtFld.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDefault;
txtFld.attributedPlaceholder = attributedText;
```

Answer (score 3):

It's easy to do with a subclass of UITextField.

Add `placeholderColor` property to easily set the color, and then observer changing of `.placeholder` to apply the color to it (with use of `.attributedPlaceholder` property)

```
var placeholderColor: UIColor = .lightGray

override var placeholder: String? {
    didSet {
        let attributes = [ NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: placeholderColor ]
        attributedPlaceholder = NSAttributedString(string: placeholder ?? "", attributes: attributes)
    }
}
```

You do need to set the placeholder text programatically for the color to apply.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! Subclassing and overriding default behavior. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 0):

set Textfield placeholder

```
let leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem.init(image: UIImage(named:"ic_nav-bar_back.png"), landscapeImagePhone: nil, style: .plain, target: viewController, action: #selector(viewController.buttonClick(_:)))
        leftBarButtonItem.imageInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: -15, bottom: 0, right: 0)
        leftBarButtonItem.tintColor = UIColor(hex: 0xED6E19)
        viewController.navigationItem.setLeftBarButton(leftBarButtonItem, animated: true)
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution is override `placeholder` property in an `UITextField` extension. It will update color of placeholder whole project. You don't need to update your code in many places.

```
extension UITextField {
  var placeholder: String? {
      get {
          attributedPlaceholder?.string
      }

      set {
          guard let newValue = newValue else {
              attributedPlaceholder = nil
              return
          }

          let attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key: Any] = [.foregroundColor: Color.textFieldPlaceholder.color]

          let attributedText = NSAttributedString(string: newValue, attributes: attributes)

          attributedPlaceholder = attributedText
      }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

open your identity inspector by selecting text field and then put " placeholderLabel.textColor " in key path by pressing + button .
Give the type " Color " and in value select desired RGB color.

Answer (score 0):

Swift 5

```
textfiled.attributedPlaceholder = NSAttributedString(string:NSLocalizedString("Input Group Name", comment: "Input Group Name"), attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: yourColor.withAlphaComponent(0.5)])
```