# how to change the preamble text colour of a UITextField

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

`UITextField`'s `.textColor` changes both the colour of the initial preamble text and the colour of any subsequent text the user may input. I want to have the preamble colour red and any subsequent text black - is that possible?

Comment: What do you mean by preamble colour ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33414757/how-to-change-uitexefield-placeholder-color-and-fontsize-using-swift-2-0/33415013#33415013

Comment: yes it's probably a duplicate, sorry for that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change UITexefield placeholder color and fontsize using swift 2.0?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33414757/how-to-change-uitexefield-placeholder-color-and-fontsize-using-swift-2-0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't set the colour of the placeholder text in Interface Builder, but if you set the text in Interface Builder, then you can "colorise" it using something like

```
self.textField.attributedPlaceholder = NSAttributedString(
 string: self.textField.placeholder!, 
 attributes: [NSForegroundColorAttributeName:UIColor.green])
```

If you aren't using Interface Builder then you can just specify the desired string directly

```
self.textField.attributedPlaceholder = NSAttributedString(
 string: "My placeholder text", 
 attributes: [NSForegroundColorAttributeName:UIColor.green])
```

Answer (score 0):

use placeholder for preamble text and can provide textcolor to placeholder using 
 `textField.attributedPlaceholder`

now you can have two colors for the textField.

Comment: not sure I follow you, any code or links on how to do this?

Comment: for the preamble text use: textField.attributedPlaceholder = NSAttributedString(string: "preamble text", attributes:[NSForegroundColorAttributeName:UIColor.redColor()])